# How to find and label the most frequent values with a tiny variance in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, eigenvalue

I have a vector `d`:

```
d = [
1.19011941712580e-06
6.39136179286748e-06
1.26442316296575e-05
1.81039120389278e-05
1.91304903300688e-05
2.19912290910362e-05
2.94113112667430e-05
3.42238417249065e-05
4.14201181268186e-05
5.76014376298924e-05
6.81337071520188e-05
0.000108396864465101
0.000130922201344182
0.000145712942644687
0.000174386494384153
0.000262758083529471
03050975943883
0.000373066486719321
0.000423949134658855
0.000489079623696380
0.000548432526451254
0.000694787830192734
0.000881370593483890
0.00125516689720339
0.00145237435686831
0.00815957230852142
0.0210146005799470
0.0507995676939279
0.0541594307796186
1
]
```

Plotting `d`:

```
plot(d, 'x:')
```

[image]

In this situation, `[M, F] = mode(d)` gives a result that I didn't want.

Is there any function that counts the most frequent values which takes a sort of tolerance into account?

Clustering can be considered. However, In the figure above, clustering may assign `d(27:29)` into the left side cluster.

Current approach is normilizing and thresholding:

```
d_norm = d / max(d);
v = d_norm(d_norm < 0.01); % 1 percent threshold
```

However, I think it is a sort of hard-coded and not a good approach.

Comment: histogram? definetly histogram

Comment: @Ander Biguri, can you suggest with more detail? e.g., how can the number of bins be determined?

Comment: I realized that you may not need what I posted. You may need to define better the way your tolerance needs to be computed, as the first values are very close to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Histcounts is your friend!

Your "threshold" can be easily translated to histogram bins if you know your range. In your case, the range is 0-1, if you choose a threshold of 0.01 then 100 is your bin count.

```
counts=histcounts(d,100)
```

Comment: `edges` as a logarithmic vector maybe, from 1e-6 to 1 (or 0.1). Not sure what OP wants though.

Comment: @StewieGriffin yes I was thinking on that, but I am waiting for clarifications